# Underline a letter on a button in Maxscript

Tags: maxscript

I was looking for a way to do this like in a queryBox where there's the Y and N of Yes and No underlined to indicate that if you press them that's what will get pressed.

[image]

Here's the code and the wrong resulting screenshot that I have where I've put an ampersand before Button.

```
try destroyDialog testRol catch()
rollout testRol "testRol" (
  button btn_test "&Button"
  )
createDialog testRol 100 45
```

[image]

---

### Edit:

Even if I try with `\x0332Yes` it doesn't work. It does but the underline isn't lined up correctly and when used before a `B` it looks a mess.

I've used hardcoded underlined letters which work which is not ideal so if anyone knows a solution that would be great to avoid this.

Here's that attempt as it may help you figure this out:

```
try destroyDialog testRol catch()
rollout testRol "testRol" (
  button btn_yes "Y̲es (Working)" width:120 across:4
  button btn_no "N̲o (Working)" width:120
  button btn_button_not_working "\x0332Button (Not Working)" width:120
  button btn_yes_not_working "\x0332Yes (Kinda Working)" width:120
  )
createDialog testRol 525 45
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your expectations, you could use a .NET button inside a rollout control <strike>but you have to style it yourself to match the theme</strike> and use a system style to make it look like maxscript button:

```
try destroyDialog testRol catch()
rollout testRol "MXS + .NET"
(
    dotNetControl btnMakeCylinder "Button" text:"&Make Cylinder" width:120 height:25
    on btnMakeCylinder mouseClick evnt arg do with undo on Cylinder isSelected:on
    on testRol open do btnMakeCylinder.FlatStyle = btnMakeCylinder.FlatStyle.System
)
createDialog testRol
```

Or you can use the MaxForm where the button will inherit the colors but it will still not look like the rest of the UI:

```
(
    local form = dotNetObject "MaxCustomControls.MaxForm"
    form.Text = ".NET form"

    fn makeCylinder = with undo on Cylinder isSelected:on

    local btnMakeCylinder = dotNetObject "Button"
    btnMakeCylinder.Text = "&Make Cylinder"
    dotNet.addEventHandler btnMakeCylinder "MouseClick" makeCylinder

    form.Controls.Add btnMakecylinder
    form.ShowModeless()
)
```

Or you can use Qt UI that comes with its own set of shortcomings (like having to always explicitly specify undo records) and it's rather verbose:

```
(
    local legacy = (python.import "sys").version_info[1] < 3
    local QtGui = python.import "PySide2.QtGui"
    local QtWidgets = python.import "PySide2.QtWidgets"
    local GetQMaxMainWindow = (if legacy then python.import "MaxPlus" else python.import "qtmax").GetQMaxMainWindow

    if isProperty ::testQtDialog #close do testQtDialog.close()
    testQtDialog = QtWidgets.QDialog(GetQMaxMainWindow())
    testQtDialog.setWindowTitle "Qt Window"

    local dialogLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

    fn makeCylinder = with undo on Cylinder isSelected:on

    local btnMakeCylinder = QtWidgets.QPushButton "&Make Cylinder"
    btnMakeCylinder.clicked.connect makeCylinder
    dialogLayout.addWidget btnMakeCylinder

    testQtDialog.setLayout dialogLayout
    testQtDialog.show()
)
```

From 2022 you can also make Qt windows with native max controls this way:

```
if isKindOf testQtRol RolloutClass do UIAccessor.closeDialog testQtRol.hwnd
rollout testQtRol "Qt Rollout"
(
    QtButton btnMakeCylinder "&Make cylinder" row:0 column:2
    on btnMakeCylinder pressed do with undo on Cylinder isSelected:on
)
createQtDialog testQtRol
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer although unfortunately no method to do it with the standard control which is a shame. I'll take a look-see if the .NET button can be styled to match the built-in button. What're your thoughts on how I hardcoded the Y like `Y̲es`? Edit, when the script is encryted it does this so hardcoding is no good. [https://i.imgur.com/xZci87d.png](https://i.imgur.com/xZci87d.png " Image: https://i.imgur.com/xZci87d.png")

Comment: if you use `btn.FlatStyle = btn.FlatStyle.System` on the dotNet button it'll look exactly like the button in Max. I got this from DenisT [here](https://forums.cgsociety.org/t/3dsmax-style-net-button-dll/1578298/2?). So I ended up going with the .NET button control and it works great. You can add that style to the answer and I'll mark it as accepted :) Thanks @Swordslayer.

Comment: Nice one, DenisT is the man :) Edited.

Comment: Yeah, I was amazed it was something so obscure and simple. I did a search through my maxscript snippets and other examples and the only one to use this is the [Show DotNet Properties](http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/show-dotnet-properties) script by Kstudio. PS. I Can't believe I taught you something (well passed it on at least!)